# using ssl_verify_client on, I receive "No Required SSL certificate was sent"

Tags: docker, nginx, openssl

### Summary

I am running an nginx docker container, a self-signed cert, and I am testing connectivity via the command line curl.
As long as I do not use ssl_verify_client, I am able to connect to the server without issue.  But when using it, I receive

```
400 No required SSL certificate was sent
```

There are a lot of variables, and I must be missing something, so I will show the steps.

### Steps

#### Certificate creation (via openssl)

- cert_config.txt:

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=ThisState
L=MyCity
O=MyOrganization
OU=MyOU
emailAddress=emailaddess@domain.com
CN=my-srv-01

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = my-srv-01
```

- generation of the certs:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout nginx-selfsigned.key -out nginx-selfsigned.crt  -extensions req_ext -config cert_config.txt
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr -extensions req_ext -config cert_config.txt
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in client.csr -CA nginx-selfsigned.crt -CAkey nginx-selfsigned.key -set_serial 2 -out client.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12
```

#### Nginx configuration

```
server { 
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  my-srv-01;
    root         html;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/client.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

#### Testing with curl:

```
curl -k -v -key /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-selfsigned.key -cacert /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-selfsigned.crt -cert /etc/nginx/conf.d/client.crt https://my-srv-01
```

yields (amongst the html and connection parameters):

```
400 No required SSL certificate was sent
```

But if I remove the ssl_verify_client option, curl displays the proper webpage.

I'm obviously missing something, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `ssl_client_certificate` is the CA that signed the client's certificate, not the client's certificate itself.

Comment: I tested by changing the ssl_client_certificate to "nginx-selfsigned.crt", and running the original curl test and also the curl test with the -cert changed to nginx-selfsigned.crt.  Same response occurs.  Any other ideas?